# GeoRegionValuePlot does not show Legends

Tags: geography

I have a problem with `GeoRegionValuePlot`. These are the settings:

```
europe = CountryData[
  EntityClass["Country", "EconomicAndMonetaryUnion"]]
```

to fetch the entities of EU. Now I want to plot different data. Everything is fine, but for "PhoneLines" the legend is missing. Example:

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[europe -> "Area"]
```

delivers: (with legend)

[image: Area plot]

But entering

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[europe -> "PhoneLines"]
```

I get (no legend)

[image: Phone line plot]

The problem is not (as far as I can see) that there are no units when asking about phone lines. The corresponding values are also there, This:

```
CountryData[#, "PhoneLines"] & /@ europe
```

delivers the values. I tried different settings for PlotRange etc. but with no effort. Has anyone an idea, what could be the reason for the different "behavior" ?

Comment: Notice that explictly supplying the data works, for example `GeoRegionValuePlot[Thread[europe -> (CountryData[#, "PhoneLines"] & /@ europe)]]`